# Ray Tracing C# Triangle Intersection

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, linear-algebra, raytracing

So basicly I want to reflect a ray over a triangle. Here's my ray class

```
public sealed class Ray
{
    public readonly Point3D Source;
    public readonly Point3D Direction;

    public readonly Color Light;

    public Ray(Point3D source, Point3D direction, Color light)
    {
        if (source == direction)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Source and Direction cannot be equal");
        }

        this.Source = source;
        this.Direction = direction;

        this.Light = light;
    }
}
```

Heres my Point3D class

```
public struct Point3D : IEquatable<Point3D>
{
    public static readonly Point3D Zero = new Point3D();

    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;

    public Point3D(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Point3D))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Equals((Point3D)obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Point3D one, Point3D two)
    {
        return one.Equals(two);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Point3D one, Point3D two)
    {
        return !one.Equals(two);
    }

    public static Point3D operator *(float n, Point3D v)
    {
        return new Point3D(v.X * n, v.Y * n, v.Z * n);
    }
    public static Point3D operator +(Point3D v1, Point3D v2)
    {
        return new Point3D(v1.X + v2.X, v1.Y + v2.Y, v1.Z + v2.Z);
    }
    public static Point3D operator -(Point3D v1, Point3D v2)
    {
        return new Point3D(v1.X - v2.X, v1.Y - v2.Y, v1.Z - v2.Z);
    }

    public static float operator *(Point3D v1, Point3D v2)
    {
        return (v1.X * v2.X) + (v1.Y * v2.Y) + (v1.Z * v2.Z);
    }
    public static float Magnitude(Point3D v)
    {
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(v * v);
    }

    public static Point3D Normalize(Point3D v)
    {
        float mag = Magnitude(v);
        float div = (mag == 0) ? float.PositiveInfinity : (1 / mag);
        return div * v;
    }
    public static Point3D Cross(Point3D v1, Point3D v2)
    {
        return new Point3D(((v1.Y * v2.Z) - (v1.Z * v2.Y)),
                          ((v1.Z * v2.X) - (v1.X * v2.Z)),
                          ((v1.X * v2.Y) - (v1.Y * v2.X)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  doesnt take square root
    /// </summary>
    public static float FastDistance(Point3D v1, Point3D v2)
    {
        float x = v1.X - v2.X;
        x *= x;


        float y = v1.Y - v2.Y;
        y *= y;


        float z = v1.Z - v2.Z;
        z *= z;

        return x + y + z;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes square root:
    /// </summary>
    public static float Distance(Point3D v1, Point3D v2)
    {
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(Point3D.FastDistance(v1, v2));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X.GetHashCode()
            ^ this.Y.GetHashCode()
            ^ this.Y.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.X + ", " + this.Y + ", " + this.Z;
    }

    public bool Equals(Point3D other)
    {
        return this.X == other.X
            && this.Y == other.Y
            && this.Z == other.Z;
    }
}
```

and finally here is where I need my method to be realized.

```
public interface ITriangleAccess
{
    Triangle3D Find(Ray ray, out Point3D crossPoint);
}

public sealed class TriangleAccess : ITriangleAccess
{
    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<float, Triangle3D>> trianglesByX;

    private readonly List<Triangle3D> allTriangles;

    public TriangleAccess(Body[] bodies)
    {
        if (null == bodies)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bodies");
        }

        this.allTriangles = bodies.SelectMany((x) => x.Parts).ToList();

        this.trianglesByX = bodies.SelectMany((x) => x.Parts).SelectMany((y) => new KeyValuePair<float, Triangle3D>[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<float,Triangle3D>(y.Point1.X,y),
            new KeyValuePair<float,Triangle3D>(y.Point2.X,y),
            new KeyValuePair<float,Triangle3D>(y.Point3.X,y)
        }).ToList();
    }

    public Triangle3D Find(Ray ray, out Point3D crossPoint)
    {
        crossPoint = Point3D.Zero;

        List<Triangle3D> relevant = this.GetRelevantTriangles(ray);

        Triangle3D absoluteTriangle = null;
        float min = float.MaxValue;

        foreach (Triangle3D item in relevant)
        {
            Point3D currentCrossPoint;
            if (this.RayIntersectTriangle(ray, item, out currentCrossPoint))
            {
                float distance = Point3D.Distance(ray.Source, currentCrossPoint);
                if (distance < min)
                {
                    absoluteTriangle = item;
                    crossPoint = currentCrossPoint;
                    min = distance;
                }
            }
        }

        return absoluteTriangle;
    }
    public Ray Reflect(Ray ray, Point3D crossPoint, Triangle3D intersect)
    {
        //need this to be realized
        //please help
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Finish this Up:
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ray"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<Triangle3D> GetRelevantTriangles(Ray ray)
    {
        return this.allTriangles;
    }

    private bool RayIntersectTriangle(Ray ray, Triangle3D triangle, out Point3D crossPoint)
    {
        // Find vectors for two edges sharing vert0
        Point3D edge1 = triangle.Point2 - triangle.Point1;
        Point3D edge2 = triangle.Point3 - triangle.Point1;

        // Begin calculating determinant - also used to calculate barycentricU parameter
        Point3D pvec = Point3D.Cross(ray.Direction, edge2);

        // If determinant is near zero, ray lies in plane of triangle
        float det = edge1 * pvec;
        if (det < 0.0001f)
        {
            crossPoint = Point3D.Zero;
            return false;
        }

        // Calculate distance from vert0 to ray origin
        Point3D tvec = ray.Source - triangle.Point1;

        // Calculate barycentricU parameter and test bounds
        float barycentricU = tvec * pvec;
        if (barycentricU < 0.0f || barycentricU > det)
        {
            crossPoint = Point3D.Zero;
            return false;
        }

        // Prepare to test barycentricV parameter
        Point3D qvec = Point3D.Cross(tvec, edge1);

        // Calculate barycentricV parameter and test bounds
        float barycentricV = ray.Direction * qvec;
        if (barycentricV < 0.0f || barycentricU + barycentricV > det)
        {
            crossPoint = Point3D.Zero;
            return false;
        }

        // Calculate pickDistance, scale parameters, ray intersects triangle
        float pickDistance = edge2 * qvec;
        float fInvDet = 1.0f / det;


        pickDistance *= fInvDet;
        barycentricU *= fInvDet;
        barycentricV *= fInvDet;

        crossPoint = MathHelper.BaryCentric(triangle, barycentricU, barycentricV);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thank you. 
P.S have patience with me... I'm just 15 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that if you have a ray that intersects with a triangle, your Reflect function should return a ray that originates at that intersection and heads off in a new direction (like light on a mirror).

That said, we already have the ray source (crossPoint).

The formula for the reflected vector (direction of the ray) is R=V−2N(V⋅N) where V is the inverted direction of the incoming ray (as if it originated from the object) and N is the normal vector of the triangle.

With your code, you should just need to something like:

```
public Ray Reflect(Ray ray, Point3D crossPoint, Triangle3D intersect)
{
    Point3D V = -ray.Direction.Normalize();
    return new Ray(crossPoint, 
                   V - 2 * intersect.Normal * (V * intersect.Normal), 
                   Color.white);
}
```

Also, if your triangle structure doesn't have the normal, you calculate it using the cross product of the vectors that form each side.

Comment: What is the bug in my normalize function? And Thank You!

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Didn't notice it multiplied by the original vector. Thought it was returning a float.

Comment: Also what is intersect.Normal because intersect is a triangle?

Comment: Right. Your triangle structure will need a normal vector (or it will need to be calculated).

Comment: So what will the first line be?    Point3D V = Point3D.Normalize(ray)

Comment: V is the vector that basically points the opposite direction as the incoming ray, so it's the inverse of the direction that has been normalized.

Comment: so what will the - operator be?

Comment: You could implement it on Point3D or just use Point3D.Zero-ray.Direction.Normalize();

Comment: I just want to thank you. I'm really naïve in this field. Last question how do you find the normal vector of a triangle? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
public Ray Reflect(Ray ray, Point3D crossPoint, Triangle3D intersect)
{
  // find normal of intersect triangle

  Point3D normal = Point3D.Cross( intersect.Point2 - intersect.Point1,
                                  intersect.Point3 - intersect.Point1 );

  normal = Point3D.Normalize( normal );

  // find ray part before intersection

  Point3D inbound = crossPoint - ray.Source;

  // find projection of inbound ray to normal

  Point3D projection = (normal * inbound) * normal;

  // find lateral component of inbound ray

  Point3D lateral = inbound - projection;

  // find outbound direction

  Point3D direction = (ray.Source + 2 * lateral) - crossPoint;

  direction = Point3D.Normalize( direction );

  // I assume your direction is unit vector (magnitude = 1)
  // if not multiply it with magnitude you want to be

  // direction = ... * direction;

  return new Ray( crossPoint, direction, ray.Color );
}
```

Comment: From 20 years of experience :-). I worked on those problems many years ago so when I saw your question I could not resist. If you really want to understand what's happening here you should become familiar with vector arithmetic. You actually implement those operations in your code but it seems you are not fully understand them. With that knowledge and correct problem setup you can derive math like this without need to search for ready solutions. Basic vector arithmethic tutorials could be found online.